# Scala Spark connect to remote cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, remote-access

I wish to connect to a remote cluster and execute a Spark process. 
So, from what I have read, this is specified in the SparkConf.

```
 val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("MyAppName")
  .setMaster("spark://my_ip:7077")
```

Where my_ip is the IP address of my cluster. 
Unfortunately, I get connection refused. So, I am guessing some credentials must be added to connect correctly. How would I specify the credentials? It seems it would be done with .set(key, value), but have no leads on this.

Comment: are you connecting to a Spark standalone cluster or Yarn?

Comment: @jamborta  I am connecting to Yarn

Comment: Try create certificate for ssh session and make sure it works also check if firewall allow this port to connect

Comment: @Pavel Yes I am able to connect via ssh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things missing:

- The cluster manager should be set to `yarn` (setMaster("yarn")) and the deploy-mode to `cluster`,
  your current setup is used for Spark standalone. More info here:
  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties
- Also, you need to get `yarn-site.xml` and `core-site.xml` files from the cluster and put them in `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`, so that Spark can pick up yarn settings, such as the IP of your master node. More info: https://theckang.github.io/2015/12/31/remote-spark-jobs-on-yarn.html

By the way, this would work if you use `spark-submit` to submit a job, programatically it's more complex to achieve it and could only use `yarn-client` mode which is tricky to setup remotely.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to launch application in yarn using spark you should use `--master yarn` for your `spark-submi`t command or `setMaster("yarn")` in app configuration initialization.
2. If case to send `"spark-submit"` command from remote host can be used popuar [Java Secure Channel (JSCH)](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) of course environmental parameter should be set on cluster properly